# Angular Only getting 1 value from method how can i can multiple results

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I have this problem. I can't get out more results than the one that's typed inside of the method. There is a table with different rows when clicking on a row routing takes u to a detail page about that certain page. Now the problem is I only get the selected one.

[0] is the only result I get..

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) => {
    this.service.getData().subscribe((world: any) => {
      this.country = world.Country.filter(
        (country: Country) => country.Code = params.get('code'))[0];
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: From the code you provide, you set this.country to be the first entry in the filtered world.Country list. If you remove the [0] you would get more results?

Comment: Can you give an example data set ?

Comment: No I get 0 results what so ever

Comment: i'm not sure actually I want the correct result

Comment: When using == or === the results show nothing at all

Comment: anyway, the `=` in the filter is *probably* a wrong thing to do. But without your providing some concrete data, it's hard to understand more. What happens if you remove the filter ? (`this.country = world.Country;`)

Comment: `console.log(params)` show this result

Comment: when console logging it we get ParamsAsMap we get keys (array(1))

Comment: 0:code length:1

Comment: If you do a `console.log(world)`, what is being shown ?

Comment: I get all the data from the world file. In this case what we are looking for Is Countries in which has it's own fillings. The country at the top result is the one we are getting out which is our problem. Clicking on another row in the table we get only get the first again.